# Why does git diff-tree show always show rename as add and delete

Tags: git, git-diff, git-diff-tree

In two test commits, wherein the first had only the operation `git mv file moved_file`, and the second only `mv moved_file moved_again_file && git add -A moved_file moved_again_file`, both appear as renames in `git status` before commit, but in `git commit --verbose` they show as new and removed files.

I'm expecting `git diff-tree HEAD` after each commit to show one `R` (rename) status but I keep getting two: an `A` and a `D`.

I'm trying to write a script that will perform actions based on file statuses but I can't properly plan for `R` (or `C`) statuses if they always show up as add/delete.

Git is version 1.8.3.1, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `git diff-tree` command is a *plumbing* command, not a *porcelain* command, so that it has predictable behavior.

One of these is that rename detection is *off unless explicitly turned on*.  Contrast this with, e.g., `git diff`, which is a *porcelain* command and therefore sets rename detection based on your personal configuration for `diff.renames`.

To get rename detection turned on, add `-M` or `--find-renames` (and their optional thresholds).  Use `-C` or `--find-copies` (with their optional thresholds) to find copies; add `--find-copies-harder` if desired.

Comment: I know it's a plumbing command, that's why I'm using it for input. I just didn't know those options had to be enabled as the man page has nothing about that in the `RAW OUTPUT FORMAT` section, nor more about each option outside of their descriptions.

Comment: Yes, the documentation ... well, not to put too fine a point on it, sucks :-) It's particularly bad in that a lot of the diff-generating commands have different default behaviors in some of the trickier corner cases, but there is zero mention of this anywhere.